# Let $T : V \to V$ be a linear transformation such that $T^2 = 0$. Choose the correct statement(s).

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T : V \to V$ be a linear transformation such that $T^2 = 0$. Then, choose the correct statement(s).

$a$. Kernel of $T$ is a subset of image of $T$

$b$. Image of $T$ is a subset of kernel of $T$.

$c$  $T$ is $0$ linear transformation.

$d$. $T$ is non singular linear transformation.

$c$ and $d$ are incorrect.

I'm confused between $a$ and $b$.
I took an example of a nill potent matrix of index $2$, and option $b$ seems to be true. But I'm not sure.

How to select from $a$ and $b?$

Comment: What's $T^\circ$?

Comment: Try $T \circ T$, written "\$T \circ T\$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T(T(v))=0$ and so $T(v)\in$ Ker$(T)$. Hence (b) is true.

Consider (a)  when all $T(v)=0$. Then the kernel is all of $V$ whilst the image is only {$0$}. So (a) is not true in general.

Answer (score 1):

Take $v \in Im(T)$, i.e. $v=T(w)$ for some $w \in V$. Now $T(v)=T(T(w))=0$, hence $v \in Ker(T)$.

It follows that $Im(T) \subseteq Ker(T)$.